# 3x3 Average filter in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I've written code to smooth an image using a 3x3 averaging filter, however the output is strange, it is almost all black. Here's my code.

```
function [filtered_img] = average_filter(noisy_img)
    [m,n] = size(noisy_img);
    filtered_img = zeros(m,n);
    for i = 1:m-2
        for j = 1:n-2
            sum = 0;
            for k = i:i+2
                for l = j:j+2
                    sum = sum+noisy_img(k,l);
                end
            end
            filtered_img(i+1,j+1) = sum/9.0;
        end
    end
end
```

I call the function as follows:

```
img=imread('img.bmp');
filtered = average_filter(img);
imshow(uint8(filtered));
```

I can't see anything wrong in the code logic so far, I'd appreciate it if someone can spot the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you're working with grayscal images, you should replace the inner two for loops with :

```
filtered_img(i+1,j+1) = mean2(noisy_img(i:i+2,j:j+2));
```

Does it change anything?

EDIT: don't forget to reconvert it to uint8!!

```
filtered_img = uint8(filtered_img);
```

Edit 2: the reason why it's not working in your code is because `sum` is saturating at 255, the upper limit of uint8. `mean` seems to prevent that from happening

Comment: It did work in fact, but I don't understand why. What was wrong with my code?.

Comment: I also remember before I wanted to sum some values over an image, and it wasn't working as intented when used nested loops, but it worked fine when I used a predefined function. Any reason for that?

Comment: the upper limit on sum is 255, so you need to set it to double beforehand

Comment: Thank you so much, that explains it.

Comment: my bad, you need to cast noisy_img to double. uint8 seems to override doule

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and now it works using my initial code. Thank you very much.

Comment: @turingcomplete great, but know that Matlab users should avoid `for loops` if possible/legible as it tends to be less efficient.

Comment: You can also use mean2() instead of mean(mean()). Just so you know, std2 also exists and works similarly.

Comment: @Bill I was looking for that command.... hidden away in the image processing toolbox. Thx

Comment: How making this changes shows it is a 3 x 3 filter?

Answer (score 2):

another option:

```
 f = @(x) mean(x(:));
 filtered_img = nlfilter(noisy_img,[3 3],f);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
img = imread('img.bmp');
filtered = imfilter(double(img), ones(3) / 9, 'replicate');
imshow(uint8(filtered));
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement neighborhood operation of sum of product operation between an image and a filter of size 3x3, the filter should be averaging filter.
Then use the same function/code to compute Laplacian(2nd order derivative, prewitt and  sobel operation(first order derivatives).
Use a simple 10*10 matrix to perform these operations
need matlab code

Answer (score 0):

Tangentially to the question:

Especially for 5x5 or larger window you can consider averaging first in one direction and then in the other and you save some operations. So, point at 3 would be (P1+P2+P3+P4+P5). Point at 4 would be (P2+P3+P4+P5+P6). Divided by 5 in the end. So, point at 4 could be calculated as P3new + P6 - P2. Etc for point 5 and so on. Repeat the same procedure in other direction. 
Make sure to divide first, then sum.

I would need to time this, but I believe it could work a bit faster for larger windows. It is sequential per line which might not seem the best, but you have many lines where you can work in parallel, so it shouldn't be a problem.

This first divide, then sum also prevents saturation if you have integers, so you might use the approach even in 3x3 case, as it is less wrong (though slower) to divide twice by 3 than once by 9. But note that you will always underestimate final value with that, so you might as well add a bit of bias (say all values +1 between the steps).

Answer (score -1):

```
img=imread('camraman.tif');
nsy-img=imnoise(img,'salt&pepper',0.2);
imshow('nsy-img');
h=ones(3,3)/9;
avg=conv2(img,h,'same');
imshow(Unit8(avg));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.